# Check when an SQLite database/table was last updated (PHP)

Tags: php, sqlite

Is there any way to check when an SQLite db was last updated?
Alternatively is there any way to do it for a specific table?

Since SQLite is a file based db I guess I can look at the date on the file but I am not sure I can rely on that.

Comment: it seems to me that since sqlite db is a file after all than last update of the whole DB could be resolved using filemtime(), but how to get a table last update time this is a really interesting for me too

Comment: I am also looking for such kind information, but I don't especially need the date only to know whether its contents has changed or not. I am thinking of comparison of a fast hash of the whole database file itself, at an initial reference time and at the current time. md5 or something like this.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but in case someone else reads this please see this post:

[Android check when table was last updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537465/android-check-when-table-was-last-updated)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be achieved by [SQLite TRIGGERS](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

Comment: ...how?  (See "[answer]")